# Having trouble converting strings to variables using sklearn onehotencoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I need to convert strings to binary using OneHotEncoder. The columns i need to change from the data are the 2nd and 3rd columns. Changing the likes of gender and locations to binary.

I have pulled some code given to us by my tutor. I have changed some things to match my my code however the are things I am not too sure what I need to change. When I print spreadsheet.iloc[1, 3] that I get an error TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'str'].

I am aware there are some bits of the code that need to be changed however I am unsure which and any help would be greatly appreciated. I have attached a picture of both data and error message.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

spreadsheet = pd.read_csv('/Users/davidforsythe/Downloads/diagnose3.csv')

X = spreadsheet.iloc[:, 1:14].values

y = spreadsheet.iloc[:, -1].values

encoder = OneHotEncoder()

X2 = X[:,1:3].reshape(-1,1)

X3 = encoder.fit_transform(X2).toarray()

X = np.concatenate((X3,X[:,0:3]),axis=1)

X = X[:, 1:]

print(spreadsheet.iloc[:, 1:3])
```

[[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42iuL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcFVA.png)

[TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFRZ9.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the data, I have observed that you are selecting features of type "str" and "float", which is causing the issue. Note that OneHotEncoding might only work for categorical features, also known as categorical variables. You have two categorical variables in your dataset "Gender" and "Location".

Secondly, It is crucial to notice that you cannot use OneHotEncoder immediately with categorical variables. You first need to LabelEncode those variables using the `LabelEncoder` from the same `sklearnlearn.Preprocessing` module and then use the OneHotEncoder.

So I would rather

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

# Extract the Categorical Variables
categorical_variables = spreadsheet[["Gender", "Location"]]

# Make LabelEncoder Object
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

# Then fit and transform the whole categorical variable
label_encoded_features = label_encoder.fit_transform(categorical_variables)

# Once the features are label encoded, now we can perform OneHotEncoding
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()

# Then fit and transform the Label encoded features
one_hot_encoded = one_hot_encoder.fit_tranform(label_encoded_features)
```

This should work for you. Once you have your encodings, you can merge these encodings to the orignal dataframe without the "Gender" and "Location" column, which can be done using the panda's `drop(["Gender", "Location"], axis=1)` method.

For further and in-depth details see, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

One more tip is that if you are not required to use specifically the sklearn's encoders, you can always use pandas `get_dummies()` method which seems far more simpler. You can check out the details at, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Good Luck, Happy Coding :)